# How to pass a dependency in the ehCache decorator declared in ehcache.xml

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, ehcache

I would like to find a nice way to use Spring dependency injection inside ehCache decorator class.
I have my ehcache.xml with the following cache configuration:

```
<cache name="MY_CACHE"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
    <cacheDecoratorFactory class="org.company.MyCacheDecoratorFactory"/>
</cache>
```

And I have the following decorator implementation:

```
public class MyCacheDecoratorFactory extends CacheDecoratorFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private MyDependency myDependency;

    @Override
    public Ehcache createDecoratedEhcache(final Ehcache ehcache, final Properties properties) {
        final UpdatingSelfPopulatingCache selfPopulatingCache = new UpdatingSelfPopulatingCache(ehcache,
                new MyUpdatingCacheEntryFactory());
        selfPopulatingCache.setTimeoutMillis(30000);

        return selfPopulatingCache;
    }

    @Override
    public Ehcache createDefaultDecoratedEhcache(final Ehcache ehcache, final Properties properties) {
        return this.createDecoratedEhcache(ehcache, properties);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        myDependency = applicationContext.getBean(MyDependency.class);
    }

    private class MyUpdatingCacheEntryFactory implements UpdatingCacheEntryFactory {
        @Override
        public void updateEntryValue(final Object key, final Object value) throws Exception {
            myDependency.update(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public Object createEntry(final Object key) throws Exception {
            return myDependency.create(key);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I can't use @Autowire to inject MyDependency directly because the decorator is instantiated via the `<cacheDecoratorFactory/>` tag in my ehcache.xml.

So to be able to use spring context I implemented `ApplicationContextAware` interface. The problem is that `setApplicationContext()` method is called after `createDecoratedEhcache()`, and no dependency could be set when `MyUpdatingCacheEntryFactory` is instantiated.

How I should pass my spring dependency correctly to the decorator?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to do it by means of Spring in the following way:

I've removed the `<cacheDecoratorFactory/>` tag from the ehcache.xml and added a cache configuration bean which uses cache manager to replace a cache with the decorator on initialization time:

```
@Component
public class CacheInitConfigurer implements InitializingBean {
    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;
    @Autowired
    private MyCacheDecoratorFactory decoratorFactory;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        final Ehcache myCache = cacheManager.getEhcache("MY_CACHE");
        cacheManager.replaceCacheWithDecoratedCache(myCache,
            decoratorFactory.createDefaultDecoratedEhcache(myCache, null));
    }
}
```

And I've changed MyCacheDecoratorFactory as follows:

```
@Component
public class MyCacheDecoratorFactory extends CacheDecoratorFactory {
    @Autowired
    private MyUpdatingCacheEntryFactory myUpdatingCacheEntryFactory;

    @Override
    public Ehcache createDecoratedEhcache(final Ehcache ehcache, final Properties properties) {
        final SelfPopulatingCache selfPopulatingCache = new UpdatingSelfPopulatingCache(ehcache,
                myUpdatingCacheEntryFactory);
        selfPopulatingCache.setTimeoutMillis(30 * 1000);

        return selfPopulatingCache;
    }

    @Override
    public Ehcache createDefaultDecoratedEhcache(final Ehcache ehcache, final Properties properties) {
        return this.createDecoratedEhcache(ehcache, properties);
    }
}
```

It works for me. If someone have a better solution please let me know.